# Shift angle orientation using atan2

Tags: trigonometry, angle, shift

I need to calculate the instantaneous phase of a 2D wave field *U* using the Hilbert transform *H(U)*.
So far it works out and the result makes sense.

Yet, the instantaneous phase is derived by using *atan2(H(U)/U)* and the angle orientation is as follows:
[image: Unit circle angles]

Is there an easy way to have zero degrees down and pi up?

Thanks!!!